# Using Speech Recognition to Select Radio Button on Android

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I'm new to Android. Currently I'm working on a quiz using `SpeechRecognizer` to choose the answer of the question

answer has 5 radio button 
each radio has 3 to 5 words

Answer example:

- Jhonny likes an apple
- Donny likes an apple
- Boni likes an apple
- Ronney likes an apple
- Molly likes an apple

Currently my App can only select the answer if the recognized words are all matched.

what i want to do is..
how can  my App select one of the answer, if recognized word is more than other.

just like this, if recognized word is `Molly` and `apple`, so the closest answer is `Molly likes an apple`, then my app can select it.
How can i accomplish this?

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work well, you have to do some workaround. My advices are:

1. to choose names, which are totally different from each other. Like: Johnny, Steven, Alfred, etc. The reason is to make sure the name will be picked up correctly and Bonny won't be mixed with Johnny.
2. when you have the properly chosen names, collect the recognition result for all of the names (johnny, jonny, johnnie, johny, jonnie) and create separate array or list from these
3. to handle these you use them as constant list or create map, according to your programming style

When you are processing the recognition result, i suggest to brake all of the results into words, so you can compare them with the expected answers.

```
        public void onResults(Bundle results){

            ...

            //this is your predefined name synonyms
            List<String> johnnyNameList = (ArrayList<String>);              
            johnnyNameList.add("johnny");
            johnnyNameList.add("jonny");
            johnnyNameList.add("johnnie");
            List<String> katieNameList = (ArrayList<String>);               
            katieNameList.add("katy");
            katieNameList.add("katie");
            katieNameList.add("kattie");

            Map<String, List<String>> namesMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
            namesMap.put(johnny, johnnyNameList);
            namesMap.put(katie, katieNameList);
            ...
            List<String> recognitionResult = (ArrayList<String>) results.get(RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
            for (String resultItem : recognitionResult) {
                    //brake into pieces the results
                    String[] messagePieces = resultItem.split(",");
                    //you process in case the length of the result fits
                    if(messagePieces.length == 4){
                        //compare predefined name collection with the result first element
                        //A) solution
                        for (String name : johnnyNameList) {
                            if(name.trim().toLowerCase().equals(messagePieces[0])){
                                //you have a name match
                            }
                        }
                        //B) solution process namesMap which contains all names
                        ...
                        //you can compare the other parts of the result

                        //remove first element of the result
                        for (String piece : messagePieces) {

                        //count matches on the other words
                    }
                    }

            }
```

I did something similar in my project, where i had commands and i had to recognize them and execute processes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/Simmetrics/simmetrics

for example:

```
float allowD = 0.95f;
        AbstractStringMetric metric = new JaroWinkler();
if (metric.getSimilarity(choice.toLowerCase(), fromTextRecognizer.trim().toLowerCase()) > allowD) {
// match found
}
```

This libs also provide other metrics that can be used

Comment: You may wanna check your code. That's from version 1.x API's been updated a bit.